# How to save/install a file into the C drive of users computer on installation of project?

Tags: vb.net, audio

I have a piece of code in my project that looks in to the users c drive to access the media folder (to play a sound). My problem lies with the fact that I have placed a WAV file called 'beep.wav' into this folder.

I want to be able to install this sound automatically into this folder if they have not already a file called 'beep.wav' in this folder. My method so far is :

```
Module playSound
    Sub PlaySimpleSound()
          Try
                My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\Windows\Media\Beep.wav")
          Catch
          End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Any questions/ clarification please just ask.

Assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this wav file is going to be exclusive to your program I would embed it into your program as a resource. You would then be able to access it without requiring it to be installed in their media folder.

Add your wave file as an Audio Resource and set it's Build Property to Embedded Resource

[image]

Then change your PlaySimpleSound Method to this, notice that I put the declaration for the SoundPlayer at the Module level so it is not created everytime you play the sound.

```
Module playSound
    Dim sp As System.Media.SoundPlayer = New System.Media.SoundPlayer
    Sub PlaySimpleSound()
        Try
            sp.Stream = My.Resources.beep
            sp.Play()
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but you can give the option to the user to open the sound(.wav) using an open file dialog. If that's not what you want, please let me know.

Comment: I was looking to have this sound play on every button press (i.e. invoke playSimpleSound method. However, if the user hasn't the file installed on their PC first, no sound will play. So what i really need is to call an 'installer' method to place it into their c drive (if possible)

Comment: You can create an installer or something more simple is place the sound file in the program folder(your .exe) and copy it to the destination you want using the IO namespace or give the option to the user to save it using a savefile opendialog